# how to edit each member of a list in python

Tags: python, function, for-loop, iteration

I am new to python and I am trying to create a capitalize function that either capitalizes all words in a string or only the first word. Here is my function

```
def capitalize(data, applyToAll=False):
    """depending on applyToAll it either capitalizes
       all the words in the string or the first word of a string"""

    if(type(data).__name__ == "str"):

        wordList = data.split()

        if(applyToAll == True):

            for word in wordList:
                wordList[word] = word.capitalize() #here I am stuck!

            return " ".join(wordList)

        else: return data.capitalize()

    else: return data
```

So basically, I want to edit the item but I don't know how I can do it.

Btw, this is an optional question: in c# I had the chance to debug my code, what do yo guys use in python to debug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
def capitalize(s, applyToAll=False):
    if applyToAll:
        l = [w.capitalize() for w in s.split()]
        return " ".join(l)
    else:
        return s.capitalize()
```

> what do yo guys use in python to debug?

`print` statements for complicated pieces of code, the interactive interpreter for anything else. I write a lot of tests through, and run them with [nose](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/).

Comment: lol, this code basically reduced my code into half! thanks @larsmans :)

Comment: @Shaokan: you're welcome. You could also have solved this with `for i, w in enumerate(wordList)` btw., but that would have been ugly.

Comment: You could also write: `return " ".join(w.capitalize() for w in s.split())`.

Comment: But that would capitalize every word, not just (optionally) the first.

Answer (score 5):

The bread-and-butter way to do this is to use a list comprehension:

```
>>> l = ['one', 'two', 'three']
>>> [w.capitalize() for w in l]
['One', 'Two', 'Three']
```

This creates a copy of the list, with the expression applied to each of the items.

If you don't want to create a copy, you could do this...

```
>>> for i, w in enumerate(l):
...     l[i] = w.capitalize()
... 
>>> l
['One', 'Two', 'Three']
```

...or this:

```
l[:] = (w.capitalize() for w in l)
```

The latter is probably the most elegant way to alter the list in-place, but note that it uses more temporary storage then the `enumerate` method.

Comment: thanks for the answer :) that was helpful! Unfortunately, I have to select larsmans' answer as he replied earlier :) but +1 !

Comment: You can also do `l[:] = (w.capitalize() for w in l)` to modify the list in place. List comprehensions are really the bread and butter of Python :-)